# Hyperledger Fabric: Where can we find the conf.yaml needed by discover CLI?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The [discover](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-cli.html) cli that comes with Hyperledger Fabric needs a `conf.yaml` but we were not able to find a sample of it anywhere in the docs. where can we get a sample `conf.yaml` that can be passed to discover CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused using the discover cli, in the section "[Persisting Configuration](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-cli.html#persisting-configuration)" you are generating the conf.yaml file. You can generate this file using a User credential or an Admin credential. Try to modify the docker-compose-cli.yaml and crypto-config.yaml (in fabric-sample/first-network) to create 5 peers for every org you will obtain a good example.